# How to deploy and access a guest executable(ASP.NET OWIN self hosted webapi application) in local service fabric cluster

Tags: asp.net, owin, azure-service-fabric

I have created an ASP.NET Owin self hosted webapi application. Below is owin self host code snippet

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;

namespace OwinSelfHostSample

{

    class Program

    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)

        {

            string localhost = "http://localhost:80";

            // Start OWIN host 
            using (WebApp.Start<LocalStartup>(localhost))
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can run Owin exe and reach out to my service endpoints like http://localhost:80/keepalive etc

When I try to deploy this as a guest executable to a local service fabric cluster following instructions at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-existing-app), publish happens successfully but i am not able to hit the endpoint. I always gets 503 service unavailable http response. No related errors in event viewer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that your endpoint is not properly configured in service fabric.

- Make sure your service is really started by debugging the local cluster
- Check your endpoint configuration - did you publish the port in the application manifest?
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-service-manifest-resources
- Look at this documentation. It only mentions APIs in guest executables, but could help you nonetheless
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-aspnetcore

Comment: I changed the code from "string localhost = "http://localhost:80";" to "string localhost = "http://+:80";" and now its working fine. Not sure why is the behavior.

Comment: Its probably due to how the Service Fabric is designed with regards to multiple nodes, this strong wildcard is mentioned in the docs I linked in my answer

Comment: Thanks Alex. The links helped in sorting the issue.

Comment: @PradeepAgarwal Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? for more information